# Xamarin IOS Stackview

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, storyboard

I'am using visual studio with Xamarin IOS and try to build a storyboard following this design :

[image]

It was easy for UWP and Android but now for IOS i don't understand when i try to use stacklayout. I understood that i must put a stackview vertical inside a view (set the stackview on distribution = fill equally and alignement on fill) but when i try then to add 3 views inside the stackview (top, middle, bottom) nothing work ... In fact i try to build a universal Storyboard which will fit every screen.

So this is my stacklayout vertical :

[image]

And what it looks like when i add 3 views inside :

[image]

**Edit 1:**

I moved the subviews in the view with copy/paste in the XML file, works better than this designer ... It's possible to say to the stacklayout to fill the width and height of his parent ?

[image]

Can someone explain me how can i achieve such layout ? (i will be crazy)

Thank you everyone ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The is expected behaviour as the same happens when you use a stackview in Xcode Interface Builder. By default, the stackview is only as large as the child views.

To have it resize and fill the superview you need to set some constraints relative to the superview.

For example, you need to create constraints from the leading and trailing edges of the stackview to the superview, then edit them so the constant is 0 - also do the same for the top and bottom.

After you have edited the constraints, you need to update the frames to reflect the changes. Do this with the [constraint toolbar](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/#The_Constraint_Toolbar).

Comment: In addtion stacklayout was not the best solution. I just added 4 views and add constraints to place them. Spent to much time on a wrong solution. Thank you for your help !